# Compare two files using bash script and print detailed diff report

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have 2 large files on Unix system which have thousands of rows and about 80 columns each.
I have sorted the files based on group of unique keys so that we compare the same rows always. To ease of understanding I am giving only 3 rows and 7 columns here.

**File 1:**

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC123" contract_id="ABC123" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0525"     
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC124" contract_id="ABC124" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0526"     
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC125" contract_id="ABC125" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0527"
```

**File2:**

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC123" contract_id="ABC123" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0525"     
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC124" contract_id="ABC124" src_system_id="PRB" entity_cd="V0528"    
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC125" contract_id="ABC125" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0530"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Mismatch in row 2 : file1.src_system_id=PRA file2.src_system_id=PRB, file1.entity_cd=U0526 file2.entity_cd=V0528 

Mismatch in row 3 : file1.entity_cd=U0527 file2.entity_cd=U0530
```

Is it possible to achieve this using bash scripting? I tried AWK which isn't giving me the desired output-

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2| 
  awk -F' ' '{w=NF/2; 
              for(i=1;i<=w;i++) 
                 if($i!=$(i+w)) printf "%d %d %s %s", NR,i,$i,$(i+w); 
              print ""}'
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: have you tried `diff` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but diff compares the whole line and gives the full line in output if there is mismatch. That is not at all readable and user friendly.

Comment: I don't think the algorithm would be easy.

Comment: For user-friendly output, I would use a dedicated GUI application, such as K3diff.

Comment: @EdMorton : Corrected my input. I do not have any blank lines in between. Output might contain a blank line, as in that way its more readable.

Comment: Do you consider perl as bash scripting also? (it is widely available and insalled by default in almost all distros)

Comment: Yes, perl is also fine if we have a better solution there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[= ]" }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        file1[NR,i] = $(i+1)
    }
    next
}
{
    msg = sep = ""
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        if ( $(i+1) != file1[FNR,i] ) {
            msg = msg sep " " ARGV[1] "." $i "=" file1[FNR,i] " " FILENAME "." $i "=" $(i+1)
            sep = ","
        }
    }
    if ( msg != "" ) {
        print "Mismatch in row " FNR " :" msg ORS
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Mismatch in row 2 : file1.src_system_id="PRA" file2.src_system_id="PRB", file1.entity_cd="U0526" file2.entity_cd="V0528"

Mismatch in row 3 : file1.entity_cd="U0527" file2.entity_cd="U0530"
```

The above assumes:

1. Your quoted strings cannot contain `=` or blanks
2. Every tag present in a row of file1 is also present in the same row of file2
3. The tags are always present in the same order in a given row
4. You can have multiple duplicate tags in a given row

Comment: Thanks Ed. Is it possible to exclude one or more fields for comparison? Date fields might differ in two files and that is expected so it makes more sense and better readability to skip the comparison for d_report_ref_date.

Comment: @Neha you're welcome. Yes, ask a new question about that as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I asked another question, please check as per your availability 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714156/comparison-of-two-file-in-unix-and-display-differences

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`wdiff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/), something like this might work:

```
$ wdiff -w$'\e[31m' -x $'\e[0m' -y $'\e[32m' -z $'\e[0m' file1 file2
```

The options `-wxyz` is to define prefix and suffix for deletion and insertions respectively. In this case we do a naive attempt to color deletions red, and insertions green.