# Comparison of two file in Unix and display differences

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have 2 files on Unix. I want to compare the files-

1. To show the the rows which are missing in both files.
2. To show the actual differences in both files.
3. To be able to skip the columns for comparison which I don't want in report for e.g. d_report_ref_date
4. My unique key for comparison is v_party_id

**File 1:**

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811925" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_party_default_status_date="2012-03-09" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="1" v_accounting_standard="SQRT" v_party_default_status_cd="UNLIKE" v_party_id="36056030" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="53565979" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811100" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811200" v_src_system_id="SMT"
```

**File 2**

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.2045" v_accounting_standard="SQRT" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811925" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_party_default_status_date="2012-03-09" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="1" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="UNLIKE" v_party_id="36056030" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="53565979" v_src_system_id="SMT"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811400" v_src_system_id="SMT"
```

**File3**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0027" other_inst_ident="PLCHS252SA20" rep_nom_curr="PLN" reporting_basis="Unit" src_instr_class="Debt" mat_date="2028-02-25" nom_curr="PLN" primary_asset_class="Bond" seniority_type="931" security_status="alive" issuer_name="CUST38677608" intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT" prfrmng_stts="Performing" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE" accmltd_imprmnt="392.69" accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0" expsr_vl="0" unit_measure="EUR" unit_measure_nv="EUR" crryng_amnt="122825.65" issuer_grid_id="38677608" v_party_id="PLCHS252SA20"
```

**File4**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0027" other_inst_ident="PLCHS252SA20" rep_nom_curr="PLN" reporting_basis="Unit" src_instr_class="Debt" mat_date="2028-02-25" nom_curr="PLN" primary_asset_class="Bond" seniority_type="931" security_status="alive" issuer_name="CUST38677608" intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT" prfrmng_stts="Performing" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE" accmltd_imprmnt="392.69" accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0" expsr_vl="0" unit_measure="EUR" unit_measure_nv="EUR" crryng_amnt="122825.65" issuer_grid_id="38677608" v_party_id="PLCHS252SA20"
```

**Expected Output**

```
Rows missing in file1: v_party_id="103811400"
Rows missing in file2: v_party_id="103811100", v_party_id="103811200"
Mismtach in row 1 for v_party_id="103811925": file1.n_pd_percent="0.16323687" file2.n_pd_percent="0.2045", file1.v_accounting_standard="IFRS" file2.v_accounting_standard="SQRT"
Mismtach in row 2 for v_party_id="36056030":  file1.v_accounting_standard="SQRT" file2.v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
```

**Code:**

```
BEGIN { FS="[= ]" }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        file1[NR,i] = $(i+1)
    }
    next
}
{
    msg = sep = ""
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        if ( $(i+1) != file1[FNR,i] ) {
            msg = msg sep OFS ARGV[1] "." $i "=" file1[FNR,i] OFS FILENAME "." $i "=" $(i+1)
            sep = ","
        }
    }
    if ( msg != "" ) {
        print "Mismtach in row " FNR msg
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
 awk -f compare.awk file1 file2
Mismtach in row 1 file1.n_pd_percent="0.16323687" file2.n_pd_percent="0.2045", file1.v_accounting_standard="IFRS" file2.v_accounting_standard="SQRT"
Mismtach in row 2 file1.v_accounting_standard="SQRT" file2.v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
Mismtach in row 3 file1.v_accounting_standard="0.16323687" file2.v_accounting_standard="IFRS", file1.v_party_default_status_cd="IFRS" file2.v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT", file1.v_party_id="NOTDFLT" file2.v_party_id="53565979", file1.v_src_system_id="53565979" file2.v_src_system_id="SMT"
Mismtach in row 4 file1.v_party_id="103811100" file2.v_party_id="103811400"
```

What changes can I do in the code to display the output in desired format?

Comment: What's your question? Please read [ask].

Comment: What does this have to do with Bash and the shell? How is it specific to Unix? (as opposed to Unix-like systems like Linux)

Comment: @wjandrea: File system is Unix and I am open for any solution in bash as well that's why I tagged it. And I guess, I gave all the details and the things I tried, but I want to get output in desired format. Please ask me if anything is not clear?

Comment: Unix is an OS, not a file system

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Comment: In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620601/compare-two-files-using-bash-script-and-print-detailed-diff-report) your input had multiple occurrences of some tags on some lines (e.g. `d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" system_id="VTX" contract_id="1130" credit_line_cd="ABC123" contract_id="ABC123" src_system_id="PRA" entity_cd="U0525"` has 2 `contract_id` tag-values). Your current input shows unique tags on each line. Which situation is correct as they require very different solutions?

Comment: This input is correct, where v_party_id is the unique value by which a row can be identified uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do what I think you want, you might want to tweak the output format:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[= ]" }
{
    match(" "$0,/ v_party_id="[^"]+"/)
    key = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = $0
    next
}
{
    if ( key in file1 ) {
        nf = split(file1[key],tmp)
        for (i=1; i<nf; i+=2) {
            f1[key,tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
        }

        msg = sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
            if ( $(i+1) != f1[key,$i] ) {
                msg = msg sep OFS ARGV[1] "." $i "=" f1[key,$i] OFS FILENAME "." $i "=" $(i+1)
                sep = ","
            }
        }
        if ( msg != "" ) {
            print "Mismatch in row " FNR msg
        }
        delete file1[key]
    }
    else {
        file2[key] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (key in file1) {
        print "In file1 only:", key, file1[key]
    }
    for (key in file2) {
        print "In file2 only:", key, file2[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Mismatch in row 1 file1.n_pd_percent="0.16323687" file2.n_pd_percent="0.2045", file1.v_accounting_standard="IFRS" file2.v_accounting_standard="SQRT"
Mismatch in row 2 file1.v_accounting_standard="SQRT" file2.v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
In file1 only: v_party_id="103811200"  d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811200" v_src_system_id="SMT"
In file1 only: v_party_id="103811100"  d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811100" v_src_system_id="SMT"
In file2 only: v_party_id="103811400"  d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" n_pd_percent="0.16323687" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="103811400" v_src_system_id="SMT"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but while using it I found that v_party_id is not the unique ID in my file. I need to use combination of v_party_id and v_src_system_id to make a composite key. I am able to sort my file using Schwartzian transform. In your code is it possible to use combination of two keys for comparison?

Comment: In case I have a string with spaces in my value then its giving incorrect result. File 3 and File 4 are identical with one line each. But Its still shows difference in those - $ awk -f tst.awk file3 file4 --- > Mismatch in row 1 for  v_party_id="PLCHS252SA20"  file1."KC10.1"=dflt_stts_instrmnt file2."KC10.1"=dflt_stts_issr, file1.default"=src_mes_accntng_clssfctn file2.default"=src_dflt_stts_issr, file1."0"=unit_measure file2."0"=expsr_vl, file1."EUR"=crryng_amnt file2."EUR"=unit_measure_nv

Comment: As always - if you got something wrong when asking your question (e.g. mis-stated requirements and/or bad example) and got answers to the question you asked then accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged and you can't format text in comments.

Comment: By the way, a "Schwartzian transform" is an implementation in **perl** of the common decorate-sort-undecorate idiom that's been around for years before the perl implementation appeared in a newsgroup, it doesn't apply to awk or any other language except perl despite the term becoming increasingly mis-used on forums. Referring to decorate-sort-undecorate as a "Schwatrzian transform" is like if I posted an implementation of binary sort in awk and we started calling it a Mortonian transform.

Comment: Okay Agreed, I accepted this answer of yours. May be I'll ask separate question for multifield comparison.